# How to add new column to an array of dictionary in vue

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, dictionary

I have defined the following fetch method as below to get the recording from the database. But I want to add a column to each record just for frontend implementation. Please help me solve this issue.

```
<script>
  export default {
    components: {
    },
    data: function() {
      return {
        versions: [],
      };
    },
    created: function() {
      this.fetchVersions();
    },
    methods: {     
      fetchVersions() {
        var that = this;
        var url = '/area/versions.json';

        this.$axios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
          that.versions = response.data;
        })
      },

    }
  };
</script>
```

Right now the versions array look like this:

```
versions: [
  {    
    name: 'Version 1',
    region: 'CBA 09',
  },
  {
    name: 'Version 2',
    region: 'CBA 11',
  }
]
```

I want to add a new column to the beginning of each record with same value something like this:

```
versions: [
  {  
    manager: '0024',
    name: 'Version 1',
    region: 'CBA 09',
  },
  {
    manager: '0024',
    name: 'Version 2',
    region: 'CBA 11',
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) (`...`):

```
this.versions = response.data.map(v => ({...v, manager: '0024'}));
```

And no need for `that`, since arrow functions encapsulate the parent scope.

Demo:

```js
const versions = [
  { name: 'Version 1', region: 'CBA 09' },
  { name: 'Version 2', region: 'CBA 11' }
];

console.log( versions.map(v => ({...v, manager: '0024'})) );
```